# VBA data-reactid for Yahoo Finance's financial numbers

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, queryselector

I googled data-reactid and it seems it won't work with VBA in most cases.

But I still think there maybe a possibility to get an answer. 
I want to get numbers in "**Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities**"

[https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA](http://Total%20Cash%20Flow%20From%20Operating%20Activities%20From%20Yahoo%20Finance)

```
Sub YFinance()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strUrl As String



    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send

    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set XMLReq = Nothing

    MsgBox HTMLDoc.getElementsById("Bdbw(0px)! H(36px)")(0).innerText






End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a single node so you wouldn't index into it as you are doing. There is no method `getElementsById` so that should fail with an error.

You could use the class and escape the special characters and index into returned collection

```
MsgBox HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll(".Bdbw\(0px\)\!")(1).innerText
```

Or pass the compound class to `getElementsByClassName`:

```
MsgBox HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Bdbw(0px)! H(36px)")(1).innerText
```

The **attribute**  (not id) `data-reactid` can vary between page and output (as it does in this case - the id is 113 for the row in the output. In this instance it may be safer to use table and row indices

```
MsgBox HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")(9).innerText
```

If you want column by column for that row:

```
Dim td As Object, tds As Object
Set tds = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")(9).getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each td In tds
    Debug.Print td.innerText
Next
```

Or

```
Dim td As Object, tds As Object
Set tds = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Bdbw(0px)! H(36px)")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each td In tds
    Debug.Print td.innerText
Next
```

As I said, the data-reactid can flex but if you want to know how to apply an attribute selector for this, see:

```
MsgBox HTMLDoc.querySelector("tr[data-reactid='113']").innerText
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! As a total beginner, I thought it definitely needed complicated tools for extracting these numbers. Could you tell me how you got the order number of <table> tag and <tr>? Did you just count it or is there any tool for that?

Comment: Thank you so much for the added code and explanation! Your answer helped me a lot though I think I should study it more deeply to understand new concepts and terms:)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following to play safe. Once the `for loop` gets the required node, it will fetch you the desired content and exit the loop.

```
Sub FetchFinanceInfo()
    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, I&

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    For Each post In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "From Operating Activities") > 0 Then
            With post.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For I = 1 To .Length - 1
                    Debug.Print .Item(I).innerText
                Next I
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```

Comment:   parentnode.parentnode +

Comment: I really appreciate your answer for the proper loop as a solution:) I will study it hard:))

Comment: The code is working the way it should be. I just tested right now @BangolPhoenix.

Comment: @SIM Sorry I just found a way to check it and thank you so much for your code!; I think I didn't import reference modules when it didn't run and didn't know how to turn on debug window